# Check content of multiple columns of one row and add new column with value depending on contents

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataset that contains channel information.
What I want now is to aggregate f.e. all channels starting with X_ and if one of the status values is "not okay" the value in the new columns should also be "not okay", otherwise "okay"

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|X_ChannelA_status|Y_ChannelB_status|X_ChannelC_status|X_ChannelD_status|X_channel_status|
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|         not okay|             okay|             okay|         not okay|            true|
|         not okay|         not okay|         not okay|         not okay|            true|
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

I already achived something like this by mapping okay and not okay to zeros and ones where "not okay" = 1 and "okay" = 0.
Then I summarized  all the columns into a new one and if the value in the new column was > 0 then it was obvious that one of the columns had to contain a "not okay".

```
val df_grouped = df_filtered.select(list_groupX.map(col).reduce((c1, c2) => c1 + c2) as "sum")
```

I would love to get rid of the string to int mapping thing since I think it slows down the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your requirement fulfilled just by using `array_contains` and `array` inbuilt functions and of course by using `withColumn` function. But before that you need to *find the column names starting with X to check for the condition*

```
val xStartingCols = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("X"))
```

And then use the column names to check for the condition using `when` `otherwise`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("new_col", when(array_contains(array(xStartingCols.map(col): _*), "not okay") === lit(true), "not okay").otherwise("okay"))
```

You should have your desired output `dataframe`

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+--------+
|X_ChannelA_status|Y_ChannelB_status|X_ChannelC_status|X_ChannelD_status|X_channel_status|new_col |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+--------+
|okay             |okay             |okay             |okay             |true            |okay    |
|not okay         |not okay         |not okay         |not okay         |true            |not okay|
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks did not know about array_contains. Works like a charm. 
I really wanted to avoid using udf.

Comment: great to hear that @user2811630, and thanks for the upvote and acceptance. :)